# How to add borders to multi-directional arrow tooltips?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have 4-directional tooltips, with arrows as an :after pseudo-element, like this: 
[(See JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3Hfhh/)

```
 <div class="background">
 <div class="tooltip tooltip-right">
     <i>i</i>
     <div><h4>Achtung!</h4>
         <p>Here is the info for section one</p></div> 
 </div>
```

```css
.tooltip div {
    display:none;
    color:#000;
    border: 3px solid rgba(117, 175, 67, 0.4);
    background:#FFF;
    padding:15px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 99;
 }

.tooltip-right div {
    left: 180%;
    top: -80%;
}

.tooltip div:after {
    position:absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent transparent transparent;
    bottom:-20px;
}

.tooltip-right div:after {
    left:-20px;
    top:20px;
    border-color: transparent #FFFFFF transparent transparent;;
}
```

I am trying to work out how to add the border to the arrow with a :before pseudo-element, as in this [demo here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-arrow-with-border-tooltip), but I can't work out how to change the direction of the arrow for the different elements. Can anyone help, or offer a link to a demo of multi-directional tooltips-with-arrows-and-borders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic principal is that once you have placed the border arrow using the `:after` pseudo-element you place another, slightly smaller, arrow on top with the `:before` pseudo-element.

The stacking is done with a z-index value.

Each arrow requires positioning with absolute values (and some negative margin) depending on where it is supposed to be.

For a top arrow with border:

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip top">
  <p>Tooltip Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px; /* as per div height */
  margin:25px;
  border:2px solid grey;
  width:250px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative; /* positioning context */
}
.tooltip:before,
.tooltip:after { /*applies to all arrows */
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
}

.tooltip:after {
  /* the is going to be the extra border */
  border:12px solid transparent;
}

.tooltip:before {
 /* the is going to be the inside of the arrow */
  border:10px solid transparent; /* less than outside */ 
}

/* Lets do the top arrow first */

.top:after {
  /* positioning */
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-6px; /* 50% of border */
  top:-24px; /* 2x border */
  border-bottom-color:grey; /* as div border */
 }


.top:before {
  /* positioning */
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-5px; /* 50% of border */
  top:-20px; /* 2x border */
  border-bottom-color:white; /* as div background */
  z-index:5; /* put it on top */
}
```

I've completed the arrows (TRBL) (with some small comments) in the attached...

[**CODEPEN EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/GkiyH)

Comment: Comments are extremely useful for working out what's going on, I really appreciate the thoroughness. Thanks.